# Multiple criteria column matching in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

I am trying to check weather certain themes from columns "match" (but are not identical) based on certain criteria. Please see example in the picture.

I am trying to check if column A = column G, then check if Column B = "Risk" and Column H = "Brand & Reputation", then it is correct, otherwise not. I have more conditions but I can include them once I make this work.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
=IFS(AND([@ID]=G:G; AND([@[Manual Theme]]="Risk";H:H="Brand & Reputation"));1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> try using <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd> or if you don't have it, then use <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,([@ID]=Table4[ID])*([@[Manual Theme]]="Risk")*(Table4[Automatic]="Brand & Reputation"))),1,"")
```

---

The above formula specifically looks in for the single word string `Risk` in Manual Theme Column, but if want it to search in a string where other words are present as well `Risk` then try using the below one.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,([@ID]=Table4[ID])*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Risk",[@[Manual Theme]])))*(Table4[Automatic]="Brand & Reputation"))),1,"")
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=(INDEX(Table4[Automatic],XMATCH([@ID],Table4[ID]))="Brand & Reputation")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Risk",[@[Manual Theme]])))
```

---

**Note:** Change the cell references and structured references as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF((INDEX(Table2[Automatic],MATCH([@ID],Table2[ID],0))="Brand & Reputation") * ([@[Manual Theme]]="Risk"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I named the left table `Table1` and the right one `Table2`

[image]